# MySQL COUNT and List 10 queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make MySQL output both the COUNT of the table and then the 10 first results.

To list the 10 first results of the table, I'm doing it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable LIMIT 0,10
```

That's easy and it works quite nicely... But: I want also count how many entries I have in total and append this to the query, so that I don't need to execute 2 queries, wasting resources.

If I do it this way:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable LIMIT 0, 10
```

It returns me an error, saying that:

```
[Err] 1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'work.SomeTable.ID'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Then I decided to use GROUP BY, but again, it does not return me the result I wanted:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable GROUP BY SomeTable.ID LIMIT 0, 10
```

Returns me:

```
ID | Something1 | Something 2 | ... | COUNT(*)
 1     Lorem         Ipsum      ...      1
 2     Lorem         Ipsum      ...      1
 3     Lorem         Ipsum      ...      1
...     ...           ...       ...     ...
10     Lorem         Ipsum      ...      1
```

Finally, I tried it this way:

```
SELECT *, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable ) FROM SomeTable GROUP BY SomeTable.ID LIMIT 0, 10
```

Which returns:

```
ID | Something1 | Something2 | ... | COUNT(*)
 1     Lorem         Ipsum      ...     13
 2     Lorem         Ipsum      ...     13
 3     Lorem         Ipsum      ...     13
...     ...           ...       ...     ...
10     Lorem         Ipsum      ...     13
```

13 is the table size, which is good, but repeating this for every entry is somehow resource wasting...

My goal was to make it output it like so:

```
ID | Something1 | Something2 | ...
 1     Lorem         Ipsum      ...
 2     Lorem         Ipsum      ...
 3     Lorem         Ipsum      ...
...     ...           ...       ...
10     Lorem         Ipsum      ...
-------------------------------------
COUNT(*) |
   13
```

I'm clueless. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your count is based on what?

Comment: @Hackerman Literally on " * ", as I only want to count the entries, not a particular item.

Comment: Isn't this something you can and should be handling from your PHP presentation layer?  In PHP, you could control what to display and also the size of the result set would yield the count.

Comment: Save the count result into a variable, the include that variable in your select statement, like `select *,@theCount from theTable limit 0,10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return two different 'types' of rows in one result set in MySQL, or any other RDMS.

They will have to be either two different queries or you can do what you have found already.

You seem to want to total size of the table, combined with the first 10 results. This is usually done with two queries, on calls `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` and the other one being the set you want returned. Do not be afraid to call `COUNT(*)`, very often this doesn't do a complete table scan, as the SQL engines keep track of total records in a table.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it with 2 queries then. I only asked because for me it was smelling "bad programming practice" calling multiple SQL request separately, possibly wasting milliseconds or seconds of processing time.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want `COUNT()`, you want [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS SomeTable.* FROM SomeTable LIMIT 0,10
```

After that query, you can make a separate query to get the total row-count:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

According to the manual:

> The second SELECT returns a number indicating how many rows the first
>   SELECT would have returned had it been written without the LIMIT
>   clause.

and:

> However, this is faster than running the query again without LIMIT,
>   because the result set need not be sent to the client.

Comment: He says he wants `COUNT(*)` (as in all records), but your solution is better as it doesn't break when filtering.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I'm not sure what you mean, this gets all records of the same query without `LIMIT`. Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: OP states he needs a count of all records in the table, so `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` would return the same as `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` if no filtering is done.

Comment: Using:  `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, * FROM SomeTable LIMIT 0,10 ` returns `[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' * FROM SomeTable LIMIT 0, 10' at line 1`.

Comment: @Fusseldieb You probably need the table name: `SomeTable.*`, see my edit.

Comment: Doesn't work either `[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' SomeTable.* FROM SomeTable LIMIT 0,10' at line 1` ... But anyway, thanks for your patience. In both answers, we do it with two queries, so it's practically the same.

Comment: @Fusseldieb Oooops, you don't need the comma, so just in case if you ever want to use it: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ...`

Comment: It gave me a warning stating that `[Err] 1055 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'information_schema.PROFILING.SEQ' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`, but both results were given. It works now. But I already implemented the other one, so I'm staying with that, but thanks =)